# JavaScript updating value of array element

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have below JSON Array and I am trying to add new object to one of the array element, but problem that I am facing is:
If I push new object for an array `array1` at index `0` of `arrayHolder` then all the `array1` elements are getting updated with new object.

```
{
  "arrayHolder": [
    {
      "array1": [],
      "array2": [],
      "array3": [],
      "array4": []
    },
    {
      "array1": [],
      "array2": [],
      "array3": [],
      "array4": []
    },
    {
      "array1": [],
      "array2": [],
      "array3": [],
      "array4": []
    },
    {
      "array1": [],
      "array2": [],
      "array3": [],
      "array4": []
    }
 ]
}
```

I am using below code to push to `array1`:

```
var jsonStr = "{\"arrayHolder\":[{\"array1\": [],\"....."; // Json String
var jsonObj = JSON.parse(jsonStr); // String To object 

var newObj = {"value": 1}; // New object that I want to push 
jsonObj.arrayHolder[0].array1.push(newObj);

// Even below code has same output
jsonObj.arrayHolder[0]["array1"][0] = newObj;
```

I get below output:

```
{
  "arrayHolder": [
    {
      "array1": [{"value": 1}],
      "array2": [],
      "array3": [],
      "array4": []
    },
    {
      "array1": [{"value": 1}],
      "array2": [],
      "array3": [],
      "array4": []
    },
    {
      "array1": [{"value": 1}],
      "array2": [],
      "array3": [],
      "array4": []
    },
    {
      "array1": [{"value": 1}],
      "array2": [],
      "array3": [],
      "array4": []
    }
 ]
}
```

I want to update value of `array1` only for the `0th` element in the `arrayHolder` array not for all the `array1` elements in the main array.

Comment: is the array holder actually coming from json?
it seems like it is not, otherwise change in one place wont be reflected in another place

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/w6k2p38a/    I created a small demo there. And how you can see it works!

Comment: This demo is working fine. `newObj` is only added to the 0th element in the arrayHolder array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with the array holder, it seems that the array holder is using the same object, and so modifying it in one place will cause the change to be reflected in all places.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
jsonObj.['arrayHolder'][0]['array1'].push(newObj);
```

Answer (score 0):

> Please try this Solution, @ehab has given you resion why your solution not working, you are using same object to complete object x and as you know object and array are Ref type in Javascript

```js
var x={
  "arrayHolder": [
    {
      "array1": [],
      "array2": [],
      "array3": [],
      "array4": []
    },
    {
      "array1": [],
      "array2": [],
      "array3": [],
      "array4": []
    },
    {
      "array1": [],
      "array2": [],
      "array3": [],
      "array4": []
    },
    {
      "array1": [],
      "array2": [],
      "array3": [],
      "array4": []
    }
 ]
}
 var jsonStr =JSON.stringify(x)// Json String
var jsonObj = JSON.parse(jsonStr); // String To object 
debugger
var newObj = {"value": 1}; // New object that I want to push 
jsonObj.arrayHolder[0].array1.push(newObj);

result=JSON.stringify(jsonObj)
console.log("result:"+result)
```

> result:{"arrayHolder":[{"array1":[{"value":1}],"array2":[],"array3":[],"array4":[]},{"array1":[],"array2":[],"array3":[],"array4":[]},{"array1":[],"array2":[],"array3":[],"array4":[]},{"array1":[],"array2":[],"array3":[],"array4":[]}]}